# how to access array in another method with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays,  which I'm using the .push() method to add to.
Is there a simple way to access those two arrays in draw()?

```
var rects = []; //for svg rect image objects
var texts = []; //for text objects
var i = 0;

function create() {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(NS, 'rect');
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "rect"+i); 
  rects.push(rect);

  var data = document.createTextNode(""+n); 
  var text = document.createElementNS(NS, "text");
  text.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "text"+i);
  texts.push(text); 
}

function draw() { 
}
```

I solve this ↓

```
function draw() {
 var r1 = rects[0];
 r1.~~~ //access attribute
}
```

Comment: There is no problem with variable scope here. The way to access those arrays in another method / function is to create one.

Comment: Your two arrays are in the global scope, so they will already be visible. If you don't want to declare your arrays as global, you can just pass them in to the function you want to use them in.

Comment: Looks like you're confusing string concatenation with array access - do you mean you'd like to reference `rect[i]` and `text[i]` in your draw method? MDN has a [well documented beginner page on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) if you're struggling with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your array as global variable. So can access it where you want in your file.